# WPF- Show() method

Tags: c#, wpf, aforge

I have `MainWindow` and `CameraWindow` in my WPF application. When I start the project and my `MainWindow` is loaded I want to open my `CameraWindow` if there is a `VideoCaptureDevice` available.
I have tried to do this like:

```
VideoCaptureDevice LocalWebCam = new VideoCaptureDevice();
public FilterInfoCollection LocalWebCamsCollection;
```

These are my variables (I'm using aforge btw) added to MainWindow and in my `MainWindow`'s `Loaded` event I tried to open my `CameraWindow` by this way:

```
if(LocalWebCam != null){
CameraWindow cw = new CameraWindow(this);
cw.Show();
}
```

but this does not open `CameraWindow` when I have `VideoCaptureDevice` plugged to my PC. How could I solve this problem? Any help?

Comment: do you ever set `LocalWebCam`?

Comment: yes, it's working partly. I mean when I remove my usb webcam then it throws an error

Comment: So where and how do you set the LocalWebCam field?

Comment: @mm8 I have updated my question

Comment: Not enough. Where do you define the code snippet that is supposed to display the CameraWindow for example?